# Windows Command Line errors that can't find file

Tags: windows, command-line

I don't know much about the command line but have been using it a lot lately. I was experiencing errors in a C application when trying to copy a file which didn't make sense; so, I tried using the the command line to make sure the code should work and get an error I don't understand.

`copy "AH/Copy testing/media.enc" "AH/Copy testing/new_name.enc"` returns `the system cannot find the specified file.` So, I tried `type "AH/Copy testing/media.enc"` and get the same error.

However, if change the directory to `"AH/Copy testing"`, then `type media.enc` it works.

I tried the same statements on different files of the same and different extensions and they all work. For example, `type "AH/Copy testing/fileName.enc"` works.

Why would `media.enc` not be found unless the directory is set to its own first? If I copy `media.enc` to other locations, I get the same error unless the directory is first changed.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be using backslashes as directory separators.  Evidently `cd` accepts forward slashes but `copy` does not.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews That's funny. I read on microsoft web site, that it will accept either `/` or \ and it has been working both ways for me and in C code also. However, if \ is used for this particular file, the statements in my question work. Yet, all other files that I tried work with `/`. Thanks.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews I'm not certain if I read that regarding POSIX functions in the Windows C runtime only or the command line also. I was using `system()` in C code with `copy` and `xcopy` and all worked except for this one file `media.enc` but the changing to backslashes works.